# jQuery click event not firing even after changing ClientIdMode to Static - ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use jQuery to show my loader when the login button is clicked, so I turned `ClientIdMode = "Static"`. The click event is still not firing and I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on:

```
<asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnLogin" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-large" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"></asp:Button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function() {
$("#loader").show();
});
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
clip: rect(0, 80px, 80px, 40px); 
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 40px);
top: calc(90% - 40px);
display: none;
}
```

I haven't tried to use jQuery with web forms before so I may be missing something, but I can't find any solutions at this point.

Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery? And is the jQuery library loaded in your markup?

Comment: It should work fine I've done it thousands of time. Have you looked at the source code to verify that the ID of the button is actually 'btnLogin'. Then check the console for javascript errors.

Comment: It is, version 1.8.0

Comment: I've checked to verify the ID. Do you think it's possibly version related?

Comment: it could be that the handler is not being wired up on doc ready.

Comment: I should've checked the console earlier. This is not a version issue or anything. Access is being denied to the javascript files because the user is not yet authenticated I believe

Comment: Would that make sense? I havent seen `Access is denied` to a JS file before

Comment: If you look at your dev tools  and you're getting unauthorized instead of a 200 response for the scripts then yes, you'll have to allow anonymous access to your scripts folder (or a subfolder you want to make public). You'll be able to tell that because the script requests will probably be red

Answer (score 0):

This works if you change your background to `red` as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/scrkd9e2/1/

Ensure that your button element is correctly named `btnLogin` and has not been modified by the ASP.NET framework.

If you're using `jQuery 3.0. Alpha`.  You should use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` rather than `.show()`